# Highcharts animation occurs every render

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I am using react-highcharts (wrapper for highcharts)
and enabled animations for better user experience,
but the animation occurs in every render, as example:

[image]

https://media.giphy.com/media/JAQVpMKbeXh1Y9jAJ6/giphy.gif

Is there a way for making animations only once?

I'll be glad for any help
thanks

Comment: Hi @LarryKing, Could you reproduce the problem in some online code editor? You can start from: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-yi81d?file=/demo.jsx

Comment: sorry, I can't. the issue occurs on page rerender

Comment: You can use code that is only related with Highcharts, just to show the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For a cleaner user-experience I would recommend using the animation only once on the first render of the component, hence, if you are using React hooks for example, use the `useEffect` hook, to apply the animation, but send an empty array as the second argument of `useEffect` so it will render the animation only once after the first render is triggered.

```
useEffect(() => {

  // Apply animation

}, []);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks but I do not control the animation from the component, it is handled within react-highcharts